# Use of increment operator in heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

I want to increase the value of a variable by using the increment operator in heredoc. My current code is given below...

```
$counter = 0;
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++):
echo <<< EOT
    $counter++ <br/>
EOT;
endfor;
```

Its output is...

```
0++
0++
.
.
```

Mean post-increment operator is not working.

I have also tried pre-increment, like given below...

```
echo <<< EOT
   ++$counter <br/>
EOT;
```

Its output is...

```
++0
++0
.
.
```

Mean pre-increment operator is also not working.

I have also tried to put increment operation inside curly braces, like given below...

```
echo <<< EOT
    {++$counter} <br/>
EOT;
```

But again no luck. Output is....

```
{++0} 
{++0} 
.
.
```

I have also searched it on google but didn't find anything useful.

I know if I can increase value before heredoc then I can print it in here doc correctly

```
$counter = 0;
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++):
++$counter;
echo <<< EOT
    $counter <br/>
EOT;
endfor;
```

It works fine.

But I want to use increment operator in heredoc, just like we use in case of single or double quoted with `echo`.

But it seems like heredoc doesn't support increment operation.

Comment: `{$var}` works really just for limited variable access expressions. Something like `{$countupfunc($counter)}` e.g. Albeit this looks like an abstracted example, couldn't you just use `$i` anyway?

Comment: So, you found out that heredoc does not support incrementing variables. Do you have a question?

Comment: No, I didn't find it. I supposed it for now.

Comment: @mario I can use `$i`, but proper name increase readability of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [complex/curly variable syntax `{$var…}`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) does only allow variable *access* expressions, but not PHP expressions per se.

- For example `{$var[…]}`
- Or `{$var(…)}`
- And `{$var->prop…}`
- And `{${stat::$lookup}}`

There can't be arithmetic operators within the `{` + `}` itself. But only between `[…]` or `(…)` used alongside.

[image: *]

One common workaround is to utilize variable function names:

```
$func = "htmlspecialchars";  // or any other no-op function
echo <<<HEREDOC
    counter = {$func($counter++)}
HEREDOC;
```

Where you can easily use full expressions in the curly var syntax.

Comment: "There can't be arithmetic operators within the { + } itself. But only between […] or (…) used alongside."  Can you please provide any reference?

Comment: See the manual link. Though it's only described with more examples there, it lists the various allowed expressions.